# loop through multiple text boxes and validate coordinates

Tags: c#

I have multiple textboxes which asks the user to enter coordinates in the form (x,y) such as 5.5,7. I want to validate both the x and y coordinate to make sure that they are numbers. I was thinking that I could maybe split the coordinates by comma and validate each seperatly, but I think doing it that way would be long winded?.

```
private bool CoordinatesValidation()
{
    bool status = true;
    decimal temp;

    foreach (TextBox tb in pointsPanel.Controls)
    {
        if (!decimal.TryParse(tb.Text, out temp))
        {
            errorProvider1.SetError(tb, "Invalid value, please enter a number!");
            status = false;
        }
        else
        {
            errorProvider1.SetError(tb, "");
        }
    }
    return status;
}
```

Comment: I would either split the string with `string[] coordinates = tb.Text.Split(',')` and then validate them separately OR split the `TextBox`es into two each, one for X and one for Y

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a regular expression to check if the format is as follows:

```
(\d+\.?\d+),\s*(\d+\.?\d+)
```

Which means:

Match on multiple decimals (\d+)
Match with a . dot in the middle
Match a comma between two decimals, with spaces, if there are any:

https://regexr.com/3vm63

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"(\d+\.?\d+),\s*(\d+\.?\d+)");
Match match = regex.Match(tb.Text);
if(!match.Success) 
{
    //append the error message
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage Object Orientation by introducing a `Coordinate` class that can handle the parsing and validation.

The advantage of this approach is that you can extend this class with additional functionality, e.g. by implementing [`IEquatable<Coordinate>`](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/story-of-equality-in-net-part-three/) or [`IComparable<Coordinate>`](https://www.dotnetperls.com/icomparable).

```
public class Coordinate {

    // Hidden parameterless ctor
    private Coordinate() {}

    // Public ctor requires two numbers
    public Coordinate(decimal x, decimal y) : this() {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }

    public decimal? X { get; set; }
    public decimal? Y { get; set; }

    public const char AxisSeparator = ',';

    public bool IsValid() {
        return X.HasValue && Y.HasValue;
    }

    // Try to parse a coordinate text in the format "X.XX{AxisSeparator}Y.YY"
    // If the parsing is not successful, returns false and error message as out variable
    // Else returns true and the parsed Coordinate as out variable
    public static bool TryParse(string input, out Coordinate result, out string errorMessage) {
        errorMessage = string.Empty;
        result = new Coordinate();

        var parts = input.Split(AxisSeparator);
        if (parts.Count() != 2) {
            errorMessage = "Expected input in format 'X.XX, Y.YY' with '" + AxisSeparator + "' to separate X and Y coordinates.";
            return false;
        }

        decimal x;
        decimal y;
        if (!decimal.TryParse(parts[0], out x)) {
            errorMessage = "Expected input in format 'X.XX, Y.YY' with X.XX as number, but it was '" + parts[0] + "'.";
            return false;
        }

        if (!decimal.TryParse(parts[1], out y)) {
            errorMessage = "Expected input in format 'X.XX, Y.YY' with Y.YY as number, but it was '" + parts[1] + "'.";
            return false;
        }

        result = new Coordinate(x, y);
        return true;
    }

    public override string ToString() { return X.ToString() + AxisSeparator + " " + Y.ToString(); }
}
```

Usage example:

```
Coordinate coord = null;
string errorMessage = string.Empty;
var success = Coordinate.TryParse("3.14, 15.28b", out coord, out errorMessage);
if (!success) {
    Console.WriteLine("Error: " + errorMessage);
    Console.WriteLine("Coordinate is valid?: " + coord.IsValid());
}
else {
    Console.WriteLine("Success: " + coord.ToString());
}
```

This usage (with the string "3.14, 15.28b") prints the message:

`Error: Expected input in format 'X.XX, Y.YY' with Y.YY as number, but it was ' 15.28b'.`

`Coordinate is valid?: False`

[C# Fiddle for this example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/2Khse5)

Answer (score 0):

Can't you mask the text boxes so that only numbers, or only a specified format, can be entered? Then you wouldn't have to check them after the fact.    https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.mask?view=netframework-4.7.2